# spring zuul gateway in kubernetes

Tags: spring, kubernetes, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

I am introducing in microservices with spring and kubernetes.

I have gateway services made with spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul that works like an [apigateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

I define Zull gateway like this:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  use-forward-headers: true

security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
    oauth2:
        resource:
            jwk.key-set-uri: ${OAUTH_KEYSETURI}

spring:
  config:
    name:  proxy-service
  application:
    name: proxy-service

zuul:
  routes:
    service-one:        
      path: /service-one/**
      url: http://service-one:8080
      serviceId: service-one
    service-two:
      path: /service-two/**
      url: http://service-two:8080
      serviceId: service-two

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false

error:
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false
```

But I found some problems, for example, that the requests have a limit per  service, so I added the following lines:

```
zuul:
  host:
    max-per-route-connections: 100000
    max-total-connections: 100000
```

I want to know. What is the most performant way to integrate spring-zuul with Kubernetes? I have read that it can also be integrated with spring-kubernetes-config, ribbon, and eureka. But doing it is more performant?

Recently I also read about [spring-cloud-gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_glossary). What is the difference with this project? Why spring has two gateway projects very similar? Are there differences in performance? Will both be supported in the future? What do you recommend to use?